# Files can't be uploaded on Google cloud after deleting user folder

Tags: ssh, centos7, google-cloud-platform

I'm using CentOS 7 on Google Cloud. I deleted accidentally the folder with my username, /home/username, that folder was used for uploading files via Google SSH.
I've created a folder with the same name. But now I can't upload any files. Is there something else I have to configure?

Comment: Have you used `chown` to make that folder owned by the appropriate user?

Comment: @ceejayoz thank you. I've used chmod and chown now it works! Sorry for the trivial question, I'm new to Linux and it's not my field of work, but I try to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is using information taken from the comments with the aim of helping the community in general.

---

To be able to upload the files, the user performing this task should have the necessary [Linux file permissions](https://linuxize.com/post/understanding-linux-file-permissions/) to copy them.

You can assign the proper permissions using the commands [chmod](https://linuxize.com/post/chmod-command-in-linux/) and [chown](https://linuxize.com/post/linux-chown-command/).